# Transform pandas dataframe with binary columns to a more compact representation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
daytime = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=6, freq='d')
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['2015-02-24', '2015-02-24', '2015-02-25', '2015-02-25', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-26'],  
                   'HappyCustomer': ['True', 'False','True', 'False','True', 'False'],
                   'HappyCustomerCount': [2, 4,1, 6, 2, 3] }) 

df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

df.head(6)


    HappyCustomer   HappyCustomerCount
DATE        
2015-02-24  True    2
2015-02-24  False   4
2015-02-25  True    1
2015-02-25  False   6
2015-02-26  True    2
2015-02-26  False   3
```

I think the column `HappyCustomer` is redundant, since it is always `'True'` and `'False'`. I would like to transform the column to sth. like this:

**Solution:**

```
        HappyCustomerCount_True  HappyCustomerCount_False
DATE        
2015-02-24      2                 4 
2015-02-25      1                 6
2015-02-26      2                 3
```

**Optional:**

In best case scenario I can do this transformation with (SQL related) functions like `groupby` since I have to do the same job later in SQL database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) along with [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to reshape the dataframe finally use `map` with `join` to flatten the `MultiIndex` columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('HappyCustomer', append=True).unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

            HappyCustomerCount_False  HappyCustomerCount_True
DATE                                                         
2015-02-24                         4                        2
2015-02-25                         6                        1
2015-02-26                         3                        2
```